# Polar Curve and maximum width

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

> Find the maximum width of the petal of the four-leaved rose $r = \cos2\theta$, which lies along the x-axis

Here is the solution

[image]

Can someone tell me how on earth did the solution come up with the first step?

The statement "*The maximum width of the petal of the rose which lies on along the x-axis is twice the largest y-value of the curve on the interval...*"

Maybe the curve I sketched wasn't great, but I did it again on Mathematica and I still couldn't see how they notice this "ingenuous" subtle observation.

Comment: $r = \cos\theta$ is a circle; did you forget to include part of the equation for the four-leaved rose?

Comment: Woops, I deleted a $2@

Comment: Now, that makes more sense! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The petal lies along the positive $x$-axis. To say it differently, the positive $x$-axis is the axis of symmetry of the the petal. The *length* of the petal is therefore measured horizontally, from the origin to the tip of the petal. The *width* at any point is the size of the petal measured perpendicularly to the axis, i.e., at right angles to the $x$-axis. Thus, the width at any point is measured parallel to the $y$-axis and is therefore the distance between the top and bottom of the petal at that value of $x$. Since the petal is symmetric about the $x$-axis, that width is twice the $y$-value of the top edge of the petal. This reaches its maximum when the $y$-coordinate of the top edge of the petal is as large as possible.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Thanks

Comment: @sizz: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a picture helps...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this image will help: it's the graph of the petal which lies long the positive x-axis, on the interval $0 \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{4}$:
$$\quad$$

[image]

$$\quad$$ So, "*The maximum width of the petal of the rose which lies on along the x-axis is **twice the largest y-value of the curve** on the interval...*"

---

Note: one could have used the same procedure outlined above by considering the maximum y-value for $\dfrac{3\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \pi$, and get the same end-result.

$$\quad$$
[image]

So there's nothing particularly special about the interval $0 \le \theta \le \pi/4$: the same maximum width or each petal can be determined using any one of eight possible intervals.  It just happens that choosing the interval $\theta \in (0, \pi/4)$ simplifies things a tad.